# Can't delete document from collection firebase angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, product

**I updated firestore image for structuring:**

[image]
I used this method to delete documents in collections , but i don't get errors , still the ID of the product is correct.

**firebase.service.ts**

```
  deleteProdusBayonete(id: string): Promise<void> {
    return (
      console.log(id),
      this.firestore
        .collection("bayonete")
        .doc<CutiteInterface>(`bayonete/bayonete/${id}`)
        .delete()
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
    );
  }
```

**delete-product.page.ts**

```
 async deleteProdus(fID) {
    console.log(fID);
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      message: "Are you sure you want to delete this product?",
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          role: "cancel",
          handler: (aha) => {
            console.log("Confirm Cancel: blah", aha);
          },
        },
        {
          text: "Okay",
          handler: () => {
            this.FirebaseService.deleteProdusBayonete(fID).then(() => {
              console.log(fID + " => Deleted");
            });
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```

**delete-product.page.html**

```
  <ion-col class="arranged" size-lg="6" size-md="6" size-sm="6" size-xs="12"
        *ngFor="let bayoneta of this.ProduseService.allBayonet | async"
         [routerLink]="['/produse','angro', 'bayonete', bayoneta.id]">
...

  <ion-button type="submit" (click)="this.deleteProdus(bayoneta.id)">Sterge
                    Produs</ion-button>
```

** UPDATE:
I modified my method so i declared another parameter called , uniqueId that is generator randomly. However.. i can't reach this parameter if I can't reach the documentId that is generated automatically when a product is added by  `this.firestore.createId();` function.

Still , i can get my custom parameter , but can't make my method to delete the document with the same unique id as below.
**

```
  async deleted(uniqueID: string): Promise<any> {
    return await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("bayonete")
      .where("uniqueID", "==", `${uniqueID}`)
      .get()
      .then((res: any) => {
        console.log(uniqueID);
        firebase.firestore().collection("bayonete").doc(uniqueID).delete();
        console.log(uniqueID);
      })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

And the create product method I use is this:

```
createProdus(
    id: any,
    title: string,
    description: string,
    stoc: boolean,
    price: number,
    reducere: number,
    tag: string,
    image: string,
    userId: string,
    uniqueID: string
  ): Promise<void> {
    this.actualID = this.firestore.createId();
    this.firestore.collection("bayonete");
    return this.firestore.doc(`${id}/${this.actualID}`).set({
      id,
      title,
      description,
      stoc,
      price,
      reducere,
      tag,
      image,
      userId,
      uniqueID,
    });
  }
```

Please someone help.. I really can't find a way out of this
[image]

Comment: can you share the constructor() code?
Also drop this. Replace <ion-button type="submit" (click)="this.deleteProdus(bayoneta.id)">Sterge
                    Produs</ion-button> with 
<ion-button type="submit" (click)="deleteProdus(bayoneta.id)">Sterge
                    Produs</ion-button>

Comment: Is this `bayonete/bayonete/${id}` correct? Can you share your firestore structure so we can get a better understanding of your flow as a whole?

Comment: I updated with firestore structure. Also i changed with <ion-button type="submit" (click)="deleteProdus(bayoneta.id)">Sterge Produs</ion-button> but still nothing happens.

Comment: Update: if i put the unique ID of the document in the doc('id') i can delete the doc.. It seems i can't get the id of the doc correcly.. How i should get the document unique ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that on your firestore the `documentId` is not the field that you called as `id`. In order to do that you must first discover the `documentId` by querying the firestore, and in AngularFire you have to use `snapshotchanges()` to do that. So your code for the delete function could look like this:

```
deleteProdusBayonete(id: string): Promise<void> {
    return (
      console.log(id),
      this.firestore
          .collection('/bayonete', ref => ref.where('id', '==', ${id}))
          .snapshotChanges().pipe(
              map(actions => actions.map(a => {
                  const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                  return { id };
              })))
          .subscribe(documentId=> {
              this.firestore
                  .collection("bayonete")
                  .doc<CutiteInterface>(documentId)
                  .delete()
                  .catch((error) => {
                      console.log(error);
                  })
          });
    );
}
```

Let me know if this works.

**NOTE**: this is assuming that the value of `id` is unique.

Comment: I get an error .. Property 'where' doesnt exist on type ''AngularFirestoreCollection"

Comment: Yup, angularfire does not have a `where()` clause, so you have to filter it on the second argument of the `.collection()`, sorry about that, I have edited the answer, it should work now.

Comment: Hey man! I tried your method , but sadly i have some errors , one that documentId doesnt pass through the subscription.. and second catch doesnt work , even if i delete it says i need to use catch or then..  screenshot : https://imgur.com/yTIo9Ic

Comment: actually, you would have to use `snapshotChanges()` in this case. I have updated my answer, also the second catch was removed.